# Why is my console.log() not logging anything in my browser?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, vuejs2, console, nuxt.js

I have a SSR page build on Nuxt (Vue). There is a simple code which runs in the browser.

```
methods: {
    submitGeneralForm() {
        alert("submit");
        console.log('teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest')
    },
```

SSR means that site it rendered on the server and then send to the browser. This piece of code should run in the browser. It is related to the button click. Alert works fine but I dont see any `console.log()` in the browser. Dont understand it. What is wrong with that?

**EDIT:**

Here is the example [Github repository](https://github.com/camohub/nuxt-issue/blob/master/yarn.lock). Run yarn install + yarn dev to reproduce the issue. **Node version v14.17.6 npm version 6.14.15 and yarn version 1.22.11** You will see alert() on page load from /layouts/default.vue which contains this code

```
export default {

    mounted() {
        alert('11111111111111');
        console.log('22222222222222');
        alert('33333333333333');
    }
};
```

This is screenshot of console.log() in console.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237157/discussion-on-question-by-camo-why-is-my-console-log-not-logging-anything-in-m).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code is not printing the `console.log()` since it's something basic and does not require any specific configuration.
I've tested your repro and it's working perfectly fine on both Chrome and Firefox. Maybe try another browser, factory reset it or ask a buddy to try on their side.

[image]

This is something on your machine IMO.

Also, be aware of the filter on top of the console, be sure that nothing is present here, otherwise it could filter the things you see in the actual console.

[image]

Comment: would also double check the browser plugins aren't messing with the output. Preferably disable them all.

Answer (score 15):

**Make sure you don't have anything in the console's filter input  field.**

For example, in the following image you can see the word "status" is masking the `console.log()` log lines:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In your Browser you have a `Console Output` Section, where you also have some settings. There you can set the log levels, which should be in your output (Verbose, Info, Warnings and Errors). `Console.logs` are logged under the level `Verbose`, so you have to make sure this option is checked. By default this option is unchecked in some cases.

[image]

Comment: @Čamo if you can't share the code properly nor give us access to the repo, I guess that you're stuck with your issue here.

Comment: I can not give you access to company repository. What should I share? ESLint config? Nuxt config? Which one?

Comment: I add eslintrc.json and nuxt.config.json to the question.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on in a Stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Yep, make a [repro] or something. If you come to somebody and say `hi I can't console.log` while he totally can, he will not be able to help you. So, maybe giving some context or a whole [repro] is a starting point yeah.

Comment: I made the github repository. The link is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a filter, "status". It will filter anything which does not contain "status" keyword in it.

[image]

Comment: Pretty much what was told into the chat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158842/why-is-my-console-log-not-logging-anything-in-my-browser/69288597#comment122308257_69158842 On top of it, the author already found the solution as you can see.

Comment: Yup just saw it after posting my answer.